# How do I get the event type that triggered a GitHub action?

Tags: github-actions

I'm writing a custom action in JavaScript.

In my GitHub action, I want to make a decision based on the type of the event that triggered it. For example was it a push or a cron job.

How can I access this information with the GitHub Actions Toolkit?

Answer (score 36):

The *title* of the question and the *content* of it contradict to each other. You mention event *type* in the title but the question asks about something else:

> was it a push or a cron job

This is not the event *type*, this is the event *name*. The *name* can be accessed via the `github.event_name` variable and the *type* can be read from `github.event.action`. (Note the difference between the underscore and the dot.)

Yes, the naming is quite confusing. Just one level under the `on` in a workflow yaml, you specify the event *name*. What you specify even one level deeper after they keyword `types` is also called "action". Here is an example:

```
name: Foo
on:
  pull_request:
    types: ["ready_for_review", "converted_to_draft"]

jobs:
  bar:
    runs-on: ["ubuntu-latest"]
    steps:
      - run: echo "event name is:" ${{ github.event_name }} 
      - run: echo "event type is:" ${{ github.event.action }}
```

This outputs:

```
event name is: pull_request
event type is: converted_to_draft
```

Comment: Thanks! If you trigger action via webhook, it accepts `event_type` and makes it available as `github.event.action` in yml file. It's not mentioned anywhere, so I'm really thankful for your answer here. :)

Answer (score 4):

From this [page](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/environment-variables#default-environment-variables), you can use `GITHUB_EVENT_NAME` environment variable.

> The name of the webhook event that triggered the workflow.

If you are using the [`@actions/github`](https://github.com/actions/toolkit/tree/main/packages/github) package, it gives you access to a `context` object which allows you to get the event name like so:

```js
import {context} from '@actions/github';

console.log(context.eventName);
```

Both methods will give you the same result.