# Run on merge or workflow dispatch

Tags: github-actions

I want a workflow to run when a PR is merged into `main` **or** if the workflow is triggered manually (might occasionally happen from a dev branch).

This logic works

```yaml
on:
  pull_request_target:
    types: [closed]
    branches: [main]
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    if: github.event.pull_request.merged == true # doesn't allow worlflow_dispatch to trigger
```

Is there a way to write something like this?

```yaml
...

jobs:
  build:
    if: github.event.pull_request.merged == true || github.event.workflow_run.requested == true
    #                                   not valid ---------------------------------------------
```

Or a better way to limit `on:` to merge events and not need the `if:` statement? `merged` isn't one of the options [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request_target). Ideally, I would have

```yaml
on: 
  pull_request_target: 
    types: [merged] # not actually an optipon
    branches: [main]
  workflow_dispatch:
```

Comment: Better how? You mean how do you check the _name_? See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/59052527/3001761.